How to create a struct with a @binding in its parameter?
I keep getting the "Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding'" error and I'm not too sure on how to fix it.
This is the code where the error appears in ContentView:
@State private var habitEggs: [HabitEggButton] = [
        HabitEggButton(habitName: "Drink Water", display: true),
        HabitEggButton(habitName: "Gym", display: true),
        HabitEggButton(habitName: "Read a Book", display: true)
    ]

And this is the code where that defines my HabitEggButton struct:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct HabitEggButton: View, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var habitName: String
    @Binding var display: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print(habitName + " button tapped")
            if display {
                print("Yes")
            }
            else {
                print("No")
            }
        }) {
            Image("egg_uncracked")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
        }
        .supportsLongPress {
            display = false

            print(habitName + " button held")
        }
    }
}

Setting it as .constant(true) seems to fix the problem, but I want the value to be mutable. My goal is for the button to disappear once it is held, where it would rerender the HabitEggs through the array again with the eggs gone after display is set to false.

It is a mistake to try and store Views.  You should store the data that can be used to create the Button when needed

A binding is not a value type as a Bool. Even if it is a bad idea you should use an init with setter and getter : Binding(set {}, get{}).

You cannot and should not store View structures when working with SwiftUI.  You should store the data that can be used to configure a View when required:
struct Habit: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var display = true
}

Then you can define an array of these and a view to list them:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var habits = [
            Habit(name: "Drink Water"),
            Habit(name: "Gym"),
            Habit(name: "Read a Book")
        ]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(self.$habits) { habit in
                HabitEggButton(habit: habit)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

And a view for each list row that uses a Habit:
struct HabitEggButton: View {

    @Binding var habit Habit

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print(habit.name + " button tapped")
            self.habit.display.toggle()
            if habit.display {
                print("Yes")
            }
            else {
                print("No")
            }
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName:habit.display ? "hand.thumbsup":"hand.thumbsdown")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                Text(habit.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

